# Passing variable to window.location href

Tags: jquery, redirect, settimeout, window.location

I'm trying to delay outgoing links when clicked, so that googles event tracking have time to occur.

I wrote the following code, but I'm unsure of how to pass my variable to window.location. It just adds it as string "url" and not the link adress. What am I doing wrong?

```
$("a.private-product-order-button").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Order buttons', 'Click', 'Service']);
   var url = $(this).attr("href");
   setTimeout(function() {
      $(window.location).attr('href', 'url');
      }, 200);
});
```

Comment: window.location.href=url - you are over jQuerying it

Comment: @mplungjan: Is such a thing even possible?

Answer (score 2):

No need to use jQuery to set a property of the `location` object (and no need to use jQuery to get `href` property of the anchor object):

```
$("a.private-product-order-button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Order buttons', 'Click', 'Service']);

    var url = this.href;
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = url;
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: Thank's. I'm so new to this, doing things the "right way" is a work in progress.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're adding string after all.

It should be:

```
$(window.location).attr('href', url);
```

not

```
$(window.location).attr('href', 'url');
```

Comment: Ohh damnit it was so easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(window.location).attr('href', url);` without the quotes around url.